# adding second variable to first in nested loop

Tags: javascript, loops, nested

What am I doing wrong here, completely new to javascript and just not getting it. Trying to add the value of the counter variable e to sum after each iteration of sum.

```html
<script>
var sum = 0;
var e = 5;


for(sum = 0; sum < 5; sum += e; sum++ ){
for(e = 5; e >= 0; e-- ){
document.write("sum= " + sum + ", e= " + e + "<br>");
}
}
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong here ☹

Comment: The for loop has 3 statements and not 4

Comment: The last part in the first loop should look like this `; sum += e, sum++` to be syntactically correct

Answer (score 0):

```js
let sum = 0; //Initialize sum with 0

for (let e = 1; e <= 5; ++e) { //Start from 1 to 5 (included)
  sum += e; //Add value of e to sum
}
```

Notice that a for loop should have three statementes:

Statement 1 sets a variable before the loop starts (let e = 1).

Statement 2 defines the condition for the loop to run (e must be less than or equal 5).

Statement 3 increases a value (++e) each time the code block in the loop has been executed.

I suggest you to concentrate on Javascript syntax a bit more, there's a lot of tutorials on udemy, youtube, w3scooles etc..

Answer (score 0):

if I got your question, can do this way:

```js
for(; sum < 5; sum += 1) {
  if (e >= 0) {
    console.log("sum= " + sum + ", e= " + e + "<br>");
    e -= 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This snipped will help you understand what's happening.

```js
var sum = 0;
var e = 5;

var count = 0;

for(sum = 0; sum < 5; sum += e, sum++ ) {
  for(e = 5; e >= 0; e-- ){
    document.write("sum= " + sum + ", e= " + e + "<br>");
    if (count === 20) break;
    count++;
  }
  if (count === 20) break;
}
```

So, `sum` is always `0` and hence an **infinite loop**. It is happening because `sum += e, sum++` does nothing. Because, after the inner loop is complete, `e` becomes `-1` and so, `sum = sum + 1; sum = sum - 1 (this is e)` does no increment in `sum`.

So, maybe this is what you are looking for:

```js
var sum = 0;
var e = 5;

for(sum = 0; sum < 5; sum++ ) {
  for(e = 5; e >= 0; e-- ){
    document.write("sum= " + sum + ", e= " + e + "<br>");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ajeet Shah, I'm totally getting confused with these nested loops :(

Comment: @bombsaway If my answer helped you. Please [accept or vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/329117)